# Search and select cells containing 3 values in Excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to include more than two criteria in the Search and Replace tool in Excel? I would like to select all cells in a sheet where part of the cell value matches 3 specific texts, but avoid doing it 3 times. The Advanced Filter option works for 2 conditions, but I need 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean - you can certainly have a setup like this in advanced filter:

[image]

and filter like this:

[image]

which will include the first three rows.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! But how can I include blank cells in the criteria range? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to select everything if you put blank cells in the criteria range. But if you want to include blank cells in your selection you can try putting "=" in the criteria range as suggested here https://www.businessprogrammer.com/excel-advanced-filter-criteria-to-exclude-include-blank-cells/